# Cannot connect to the target at location localhost:9222 while debugging JavaScript in VSCode and Chrome

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, debugging

Trying to debug simple HTML/JavaScript website in VSCode in "Attach to Chrome" mode with Live Server extension.

But getting this error:

[image]

Yes, I have added `chrome.exe --remote-debugging-port=9222`

launch.json is like this

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Attach to Chrome",
            "port": 9222,
            "request": "attach",
            "type": "chrome",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:5500",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Same question.
I have resolved it by adding `runtimeArgs: ["--remote-allow-origins=http://localhost:9222"]` into configurations for Main in `.vscode/launch.json`

My configurations:

```
  "configurations": [
{
  "name": "Renderer",
  "port": 9222,
  "request": "attach",
  "type": "chrome",
  "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
},
{
  "name": "Main",
  "type": "node",
  "request": "launch",
  "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
  "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/electron",
  "windows": {
    "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/electron.cmd"
  },
  "args": [".", "--remote-debugging-port=9222"],
  "runtimeArgs": ["--remote-allow-origins=http://localhost:9222"],
  "outputCapture": "std",
  "console": "integratedTerminal"
}]
```

Comment: I can't add this property, says "Not Allowed": https://i.imgur.com/GCNSTpW.png

Comment: You can try to add this property into your second configuration which has ""request": "launch"" property

Comment: That's the whole point. I'm talking specifically about "attached"  configuration. This is so weird that nobody talks about the fact this has not been working for years.